# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Example code:

> ```
> let roles = JSON.parse(result[0].roles);
> if ( roles[ 'onJoinEvent' ] && roles[ 'onJoinEvent' ][ 'status' ] == "true" )
> {
>     console.log(roles[ 'onJoinEvent' ])
>     roles[ 'onJoinEvent' ][ 'roles' ].forEach( async function(element)
>     {
>         let lol = member.guild.roles.find( rol => rol.id == element );
>         if (lol) member.addRole(lol.id);
>     })
> }
> ```

It has administrator permission, so.
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NCrk.png

Evidence of error
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEDE0.png

If you want to see my db ->
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Ziz.png

Answer (score 1):

The bot's [invite link](https://discordapi.com/permissions.html) is what determines its permissions. In this case, your invite link is faulty and does not have the needed administrator permissions. You have to kick the bot and re-invite it with the link of `https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=INSERT_CLIENT_ID_HERE&scope=bot&permissions=8`.